# how to show svn:external links in http browse repository

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

this may have been asked already but I cant really find it (most likely because of how I word it), 
I have a composite project made of many smaller projects (svn:external linked) but when the http link is clicked (browse repo) it shows nothing, how do I get it to show links to the svn:externals to show up in the http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct access on a SVN repository via HTTP and a Web-browser is not the intended way to use it. The HTTP protocol is for the SVN client - that it works with browsers, too is coincidence because of the used HTTP protocol.

The only way to see svn:externals properties would be a repository browsing web-application such as [WebSVN](http://www.websvn.info/) or [ViewCV](http://www.viewvc.org/).

Unfortunately displaying svn:externals properties is not implemented in WebSVN (see [enhancement](http://websvn.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=206) request) but it looks like what you are searching for is working in [ViewCV since version 1.1.3](http://viewvc.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=434).

Comment: crud, I was hoping (short of just putting a readme textfile) that would at least reference it, I just know someone is going to look at it think "theres nothing here?" it will work obviously when they pull it down but.... just trying to make it simple. thanks